# how can I import a delimited data set from .txt into rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

So i have several .txt files with over 200,000 values, If it was less than 16k i can import and transpose, but since it's over that Excel just combines in one cell under 1 column, is there anyway i can import my data directly to a row so that it's functional?

My Data is something like this:

```
25, 36, 17, 22, 30, 34, 29, 23, 25, 23, 28, 27, 31, 31, 16, 35, 26, 34, 33, 29, 25, 25, 24, 36, 23, 29, 26, 30, 19, 32, 19, 27, 34, 35, 25, 31, 21, 26, 32, 23, 30, 30, 31, 24, 33, 20, 27, 35, 23, 26, 20, 28, 34, 25, 24, 30, 27, 20, 32, 23, 24, 33, 35, 37, 22, 30, 25, 19, 23, 40, 27, 26, 30, 30, 25, 28, 20, 31, 30, 25, 28, 25, 20, 37, 22, 32, 31, 24, 33, 27, 35, 23, 36, 26, 25, 37, 29, 32, 28, 35, 19, 23, 29, 33, 32, 24, 21, 25, 29, 30, 29, 35, 28, 26, 28, 29, 33, 36, 39, 31, 25, 31, 25, 29, 29, 32, 28, 31, 19, 33, 35, 20, 23, 36, 34, 25, 33, 28, 31, 24, 36, 33, 33, 30, 31, 31, 31, 25, 40, 22, 21, 27, 20, 30, 29, 27, 28, 32, 27, 26, 25, 29
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the txt extension to be csv (comma seperated values), which can be opened in excel and handled further

Comment: wouldn't changing into a .csv involve importing to an Excel? i'd face the same issue again.

Comment: I also tried, changing just the extension to .csv but when I import it, excel crashes.

Edit: i tried it a few more times, it finally went through but it still shows up as columns, but limits them to 3,000 columns.

Comment: What do you want it to look like in Excel? all 200.000 values seperated in columns?

Comment: I need them to import into rows rather than columns, so 200k values separated in different rows underneath one column.

Comment: Did not test it, but this website allows you to upload the file and get the data in return: https://onlinecsvtools.com/convert-csv-columns-to-rows

Answer (score 0):

You could write VBA code to open the file and read it in character by character (or in chunks of 100 characters), process it and then put in in cells

```
Dim strText As String
Open "C:\myfile.txt" For Input As #1
```

Now Loop - the next line reads 100 chars

```
sText = Input$(100, 1)
```

End loop

```
Close #1
```